# javascript if statement checking for true/false

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wrote, what I thought, was a straight forward if statement in JS but it is running incorrectly.

```
function printLetter(LetterId) {
    var studentflag = $("#IsStudent").val();
    if (studentflag)
    {
           //do option 1        
    } else {

           //do option 2    
    }

}
```

Everytime it runs, the `studentflag` var value is correct, but regardless of whether it is `true` or `false`, it goes into option 1.  I am pretty sure I have done `true`/`false` checks like this before in JS, but do I need to spell it out `(studentflag == true)` instead?

Comment: It's hard to tell without knowing to what `#IsStudent` refers.

Comment: At first glance your code looks fine, have you tried doing a console.log on studentFlag before your if statement? What was the result?

Comment: @cdhowie isn't cause `val()` returns not boolean?

Comment: @Alek `.val()` will always return you a string, just sometimes it could be an empty string. Empty strings are false and would follow the logic laid out in the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `#StudentFlag` is either `"true"` or `"false"`, then `if(studentFlag)` will always follow the `true` route because both are non-empty strings (truthy).  You need to do something along these lines:

```
var studentflag = $("#IsStudent").val();
if (studentflag === "true") {
       //do option 1        
} else {
       //do option 2    
}
```

Comment: I like this answer Just `#IsStudent` value must be either 'true' or 'false'.

Answer (score 8):

This is known as **truthy** and **falsy** Values

The following values are always **falsy**:

- false
- 0 (zero)
- "" (empty string)
- null
- undefined
- NaN (a special Number value meaning Not-a-Number!)

All other values are **truthy**:

- including `"0"` (zero in quotes),
- `"false"` (false in quotes) like `if (studentflag) //being studentflag "false"`,
- empty functions,
- empty arrays, and
- empty objects.

Answer (score 2):

`.val ()` doesn't return a boolean.

Try this instead;

```
function printLetter(LetterId) {
    var studentflag = $("#IsStudent").is (':checked');
    if (studentflag)
    {
           //do option 1        
    } else {

           //do option 2    
    }

}
```

This is assuming `#IsStudent` is a checkbox. If it's not, try this (assuming the value is `true` (as a string, not a boolean));

```
function printLetter(LetterId) {
    var studentflag = ($("#IsStudent").val () == 'true')
    if (studentflag)
    {
           //do option 1        
    } else {

           //do option 2    
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

IMO there should be more context in the question. If submitted solution works for OP that is great, but for others using this as a resource, the accepted solution might not work in all cases.

The value retrieved from an element via JS actually depends on the input itself and its HTML structure. Here's a demo explaining the difference between using `.val()`, `.attr('val')`, and `.is(':checked')` with checkboxes and radios. All of those variants can pull different values from an element depending on its HTML structure and current UI state.

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/h6csLaun/2/

Answer (score 0):

```
var studentflag = $("#IsStudent").val();//This is a string .. not a boolean
if (studentflag === "true")  //therefore this has to be string comparison
```

Or you can make `studentflag` boolean as follows:

```
var studentflag = $("#IsStudent").val() === "true";
if (studentflag) { ....
```